# How to format rows into columns, join every row untill a blank line is encountered using AWK

Tags: linux, shell, awk

If sample.txt has following data

```
Employee_id 101
Dept_id 10
Salary 2000

Employee_id 102
Dept_id 20
Salary 3000

Employee_id 103
Dept_id 30
Salary 3000
```

I would like to see the output as following

```
Employee_id 101 Dept_id 10 Salary 2000
Employee_id 102 Dept_id 20 Salary 3000
Employee_id 103 Dept_id 30 Salary 3000
```

Answer (score 6):

A simple way using awk:

```
$ awk -v RS= '{$1=$1}1' file
Employee_id 101 Dept_id 10 Salary 2000
Employee_id 102 Dept_id 20 Salary 3000
Employee_id 103 Dept_id 30 Salary 3000
```

The record separator `RS` is unset, so that each block is treated as a record. `$1=$1` causes awk to touch each record, so that it is reformatted into fields separated by spaces. The `1` at the end is a shorthand for `{print}`.

Comment: You're welcome. If your problem is solved, don't forget to accept an answer by clicking on the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' yourfile` as suggested here: [How can I replace a newline (\n) using sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n-using-sed)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'NF' file | paste - - -
```

will do it. The AWK command removes the blank lines, and the paste command separates the 3 strings with a tab character. To have the 3 bits separated with a space, use

```
paste -d ' ' - - -
```